# TypeScript and Koa 2: async/await issue with Global Error Handler

Tags: typescript, error-handling, async-await, koa, ecmascript-2016

I am writing an app with TypeScript as well as Koa 2.

However, the issue I am experiencing is that my global Koa error handler does not catch errors that were thrown in my application.

Take the following middleware, for example (this is the very first middleware before any routes are loaded):

```
app.use(async(ctx, next) => {
    console.log("ErrorHandler loaded...");
    try {
        console.log("Trying for error...");
        await next();
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("Caught error...");
        ctx.status = err.status || 500;
        ctx.response.body = "Error: " + err.message;
    }
});
```

When accessing my routes, I can see that the error handler is loaded and that the `try` block runs.

However, if I throw an error in a route (irrespective of whether I use `throw` or `ctx.throw`), all I get is the default error message "Not found" - so, any errors I throw are never caught and, therefore, my error handler won't *handle* it.

Now consider the following transpiled JavaScript:

```
app.use((ctx, next) => __awaiter(this, void 0, void 0, function* () {
    console.log("ErrorHandler loaded...");
    try {
        console.log("Trying for error...");
        yield next();
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log("Caught error...");
        ctx.status = err.status || 500;
        ctx.response.body = "Error: " + err.message;
    }
}));
```

### The question is two-fold:

1. Is my application unable to catch thrown errors because of the transpilation?  I mean, would it work if the transpiled JavaScript would make use of the `async` and `await` keywords, rather than transpiling it to generators using `yield`?
2. If the above is correct: is there any way to write Koa 2 apps with TypeScript **now**?

### Edit

I found a "solution" to get my errors to throw, but I still don't understand why Koa didn't catch them.

This `for of` loop iterates an array of controllers which I dynamically load.  For each controller, I am attaching the respective method (action.method) of a class (action.target) to a route (action.route) using the specified Http verb (action.type).

However, I am also binding the context to the method so as to ensure that, as per Koa's conventions, `this` is bound to the `Context`:

```
for (let action of actionMetadata) {
    router[action.type.toLowerCase()](action.route, (ctx, next) => {
        (new action.target)[action.method].bind(ctx)(ctx, next);
    });
}
```

The above causes the issue where errors are not caught.

In comparison, the below code works: errors are now caught by Koa.  But this means that `this` now is not the `Context` anymore.

I can live with that since the `Context` is the first param in my routes, but I don't understand why the error is not caught as all middleware following the error handler (which is my very first middleware) should run within its `try` block:

```
for (let action of actionMetadata) {
    router[action.type.toLowerCase()](action.route, (new action.target )[action.method]);
}
```

Comment: It is supposed to use transpiled code. There are no 'async and await keywords' because this proposal isn't standardized and isn't implemented yet. I guess that other app parts and beta status of Koa 2 are more likely to blame

Comment: It's working well for me. Can you show more of your code, for example how you throw an error? The order of the middleware, and what ever might be useful.

Comment: Hi there - thanks for chipping in. I got it to work, but I still think my previous implementation should have worked, too.  Therefore, I've added an update to my question.

Comment: Why are you using classes at all? Why do you create an instance of a class there instead of creating them from the beginning and then just access the instances? And then if you don't want the instance methods to have the instance as `this` then what's the point of having these functions in the class to being with?

Comment: To the first point: because I like the structure I get by using method decorators such as `@Route("/view/:id", HttpVerb.Get)`. To the last point: there is no point - it was a pure relic of me trying to follow Koa conventions re. `this`. Like I say: ctx is the first param and I don't need `this` to be the context. Design choices aside, I guess I merely have trouble understanding why the first set-up doesn't catch thrown exceptions since there are no additional `try`s that could potentially swallow them up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, looks like this was pure user error in not ensuring that every single middleware returns a promise (or is an async function).

The `async` in the following is all that was missing:

```
for (let action of actionMetadata) {
    router[action.type.toLowerCase()](action.route, async (ctx, next) => {
        (new action.target)[action.method].bind(ctx)(ctx, next);
    });
}
```